# Object become white when applying booleans

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

As mentioned in the title, I have a cylinder and I applied to It two booleans, but doing this turns the removed zones' color to white. Does someone have any idea about why this is appening and most of all how can I solve thisa issue?

There is an update, using the fast solver made the magic. Is there a way to obtain the same result also with the exact solver? And why is there this different result?

[image]

Comment: if the boolean object has a common material with your booleaned object, this material will appear on the booleaned zone. Not sure about the second question though, it should work the same with Fast and Exact...

Comment: So, should I apply the same material on the 2 objects?

Comment: If you don't want this material, remove it from the cutting object